# C memory allocationd

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, clion

```
void mem_init(int n) {
    struct A{
        int thing1;
        double thing2;
    };
    arr_A= malloc(sizeof(struct A)*n);

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        arr_A[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct A));
        arr_A[i]->thing1 =1;
        arr_A[i]->thing2 =2;
    }
}


void mem_free() {
    free(A);
}
```

I just set the struct array as global variable and solved this problem.
thank you so much.

Comment: `arr_A` will go out of scope when the function exits, and any memory associated with it via pointers will be leaked, so you won't be able to use the array anyway. You'll need to do something like `malloc` `arr_A` itself, then return a pointer to it from the function. Or, pass a pointer to existing memory into the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to have a array of struct A, so I declared the array in function 'mem_init'.

this is not what you did because `struct A *arr_A[n];` is an array of *pointers* to`struct A`.

An array of `struct A` can be

```
struct A arr_A[n]; // variable length array
```

or

```
struct A * arr_A = malloc(n * sizeof(struct A));
```

Of course having an array of *struct A* rather that pointer to the loop is modified :

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
   arr_A[i].thing1 =1;
   arr_A[i].thing2 =2;
}
```

> now I want to make a function to free the memory of 'arr_A'

if *arr_A* is your array of pointer you can do (supposing the definition of *A* known out of *mem_init*) :

```
void mem_free(struct A ** arr_A, int n)
{
   for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
     free(arr_A[i]);
}
```

else (the function is not really useful and *free* can be used directly rather than to define and call *mem_free*) :

```
void mem_free(struct A *arr_A)
{
   free(arr_A);
}
```

---

Out of that currently the call of *mem_free* can only be done in *mem_init* because only it knows the array, do you really want that ? If not *mem_init* can return the address of the array, using your array of pointers a solution is :

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct A {
  int thing1;
  double thing2;
};

struct A ** mem_init(int n) {
  struct A ** arr_A = malloc(n * sizeof(struct A *));
  
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    arr_A[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct A));
    arr_A[i]->thing1 =1;
    arr_A[i]->thing2 =2;
  }
  
  return arr_A;
}

void mem_free(struct A ** arr_A, int n)
{
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    free(arr_A[i]);
  free(arr_A);
}

int main()
{
  const int nelt = 10;
  struct A ** arr_A = mem_init(nelt);
  
  mem_free(arr_A, nelt);
  return 0;
}
```

Note I moved the definition of *A* outside, and the array is not anymore a local VLA to *mem_init* to be able to use it after the execution of *mem_init*

Compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==12721== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==12721== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==12721== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==12721== Command: ./a.out
==12721== 
==12721== 
==12721== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12721==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12721==   total heap usage: 11 allocs, 11 frees, 200 bytes allocated
==12721== 
==12721== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==12721== 
==12721== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==12721== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function isn't working because you aren't passing the array to the free function. You need to change your function to something like this,

```
void mem_free(struct A * ptr_to_mem) {
       free(ptr_to_mem);
}
```

Comment: Yeah this can be a way. But for this to work, mem_init should somehow return the local references (unless one assume that mem_init calls mem_free)

Comment: What @GauravSingh said, plus that it would not work since it's an array of pointers